# Django , Break Page like wordpress Break Page?

Tags: django, django-templates

there is any way to make a Break Page with django for using with large articles?

thanks

Comment: This question is overly broad.

Answer (score 1):

Run your content through a template filter, similar to [Linebreaks](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) (as an example)

So, you could make a "parsemore" filter, or something like that.

Documentation for making filters can be found here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-template-tags/